# How to get shell variable expansion if the value is another shell variable

Tags: bash, shell

```
level_1="hi hello"
level_2="hey "
level_3="whatsup howdy"
echo ${!level*}

for i in ${!level*};do
  j="\$$i"
  echo $j
done
```

This will print

```
level_1 level_2 level_3
$level_1
$level_2
$level_3
```

I wish to get the value of $level_1 or $level_2 printed instead.

Any pointers how this can be achieved.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `${!variable}` for that:

```
for i in ${!level*};do
  j=${!i}
  echo $j
done
```

This will give the desired output:

```
hi hello
hey
whatsup howdy
```

Comment: thanks, I found one more solution using eval ... for i in ${!level*};do
  j="\$$i"
  eval "echo $j"
done